# Install Google Play Store on ROM without Google apps

Tags: google-play-store, rom-flashing, custom-roms, recovery-mode

I rooted my Samsung Galaxy S3 and flashed SlimKat's 4.4 ROM and it has no Google Play. When I downloaded GAPPS, it says "Cannot open file" when attempting to open.

How can I install the gapps.zip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install gapps, flash them from the recovery (the same way you installed the ROM), you shouldn't open the .zip file since it is automatically processed by the recovery.

Comment: OK. So I need a laptop again? Or I can somehow install them from recovery boot you're saying?.... Thanks so much.oh one more...since they're already downloaded on my phone they should automatically be in my recovery right? Or am I gonna have to redownload?

Comment: You don't need the PC if you have the file already on your phone, just open recovery, then install zip from SD card, and then simply choose the gapps file that is located on your phone.

Comment: Yes I figured it out thanks to you. I'd posted my gratitude already...I suppose it didn't load. I just asked another question...maybe you can save the day again? Thank you so much....to think it was that simple.